# Coarse and fine grid

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, mesh

Please see below the code and guide me.

I want to create coarse and fine mesh. For 1st set of loop and given limits, result is 5*3 matrix (coarse mesh).  For the 2nd set of loop and given limits, result is 5*3 matrix.  However, I want to convert the 2nd result in 10*6 matrix without changing the limit `(if (i >= 0 && i < 5  && j >= 2 && j <5))`.

Code is as follows:

```
#define NX 5
#define NY 5

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NX; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NY; j++)
        {
        if (i >= 0 && i < 5  && j >= 0 && j <3)
            {
            int count =i* NY+ j;
            cout << count << " ";
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NX; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NY; j++)
        {
        if (i >= 0 && i < 5  && j >= 2 && j <5)
            {
            int count =i* NY+ j;
            cout << count << " ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

first set of loop,  result is

```
0 1 2
5 6 7
10 11 12
15 16 17
20 21 22
```

2nd set of loop, result is

```
2 3 4
7 8 9
12 13 14
17 18 19
22 23 24
```

I want the 2nd loop result to be 10*6 matrix to generate fine mesh.

Comment: Can you give the example of the valid 10 * 6 matrix you want?

Comment: Thank you @Rietty, I do not know how can I explain my problem properly. What my objective is: for 1st set of loops, outcome is 5 rows and 3 columns. similar is the case for 2nd set of loop. However, I want to increase points in 2nd output. That is, I need 10 rows and 6 columns. Is it possible? Can I use 2*NX and 2*NY in 2nd set of loop to get the desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating seperate variables for both loops. then I communicated between these variables to create coarse and fine mesh.